# Disable selected option in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a select where I want to disable its selected option following its selection.
e.g.

```html
<select id="elementSelect"  >
<option>SVG Element</option>
<option onClick=this.disabled=true;this.innerHTML='&check;circle' >circle</option>
<option onClick=this.disabled=true;this.innerHTML='&check;ellipse' >ellipse</option>
<option onClick=this.disabled=true;this.innerHTML='&check;rect' >rect</option>
</select>
```

This works OK is IE and FF, but Chrome ignores the onClick event.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onclick()** event is not supported by `<option>`

Use `querySelector` to identify the option and add `disabled` attribute to it.

Hope this helps!

```js
var select = document.getElementById('elementSelect')
select.onchange = function(e){
  var val = e.target.value
  var el = document.querySelector('select option[value=\''+val+'\']')
  el.innerHTML = '✓'+val
  el.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
}
```

```html
<select id="elementSelect">
  <option value="SVG Element">SVG Element</option>
  <option value="circle">circle</option>
  <option value="ellipse">ellipse</option>
  <option value="rect">rect</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.